# Log DbContext.SaveChanges Exception to the database in Entity Framework/Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my asp.net core web application, I am logging the exceptions to the database.Till now everything works fine but problem is that when the `DbConext.SaveChanges` in try block throws an exception, cannot log the exception to the database as `DbConext.SaveChanges`  in `catch block` also throws the same exception.

Here is the code I have tried so far :

```
try
{
    _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().InsertEntity(product);
     await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();//This throws exception due the model validation failure
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    ExceptionModel exceptionModel = new ExceptionModel();
    using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        await dbContext.ExceptionModels.AddAsync(exceptionModel);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // Throws the same exception that was thrown in try block due to entity framework transaction
    }
}
```

***Note: I guess the problem is causing due to the Entity Framework transaction.***

**Please help how can I overcome this situation to log the exception to the database. Thanks!**

Comment: If only you told us the details about those exceptions...

Comment: Let's say you failed to save changes to a database because the database server is down. Now you want to log something to the database to indicate that the first save failed. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The DB is down, how do I log it's down in the DB?

Comment: Ok..See the question updated..Actually Exception is throwing due to the model validation failed..

Comment: What was the **exact** exception thrown?

Comment: Exception Message: The property 'ProductId' on entity type 'ProductSpecification' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

Comment: Use some external service such as Exceptionless and don't do try/catch. Logging db errors into the same db sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Can you post a complete repro.  Using a separate DbContext to write the exception message should work fine (so long as the exception isn't caused by the database server being unavailable).

Comment: Yes! Common operation repository Context and Exception logging context are same context but different initialization but still causing problem..Try block exception is also throwing in catch block..This is the main problem, may be due to the same transaction..May be different transaction will solve the problem..

Comment: [ELMAH](https://blog.elmah.io/support-for-dotnet-and-aspnet-core/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity framework Core, I have solved the problem easily using EF-Core [Transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)

```
try
{
    _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().InsertEntity(product);
     await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();//This throws exception due the model validation failure
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    ExceptionModel exceptionModel = new ExceptionModel();

    string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                .Options;

    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(options))
    {
         using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
         {
             try
             {
                   dbContext.Exceptions.Add(exceptionModel);
                   await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                   transaction.Commit();
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(e);
                 throw;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In try block you are adding some changes to db context. While saving you got some exception and using the same db context in catch block to log that exception. Here the db context still has unsaved changes made in try block. So you will get the same exception while saving the context.

To avoid this you have to discard the changes from db context in catch block before adding more changes.

```
private void ResetContextState() => _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
.Where(e => e.Entity != null && e.state == EntityState.Added).ToList()
.ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

Edit: the above code worked for me.